# Google API issue

Tags: google-search-api

I am building react.js project similar to Google Search.
I used serpwow API(www.serpwow.com).
But if I get result using this API, it's different from the result of LiveDemo of Serpwow.(https://serpwow.com/demo)
For example, if I search "green", about the local_results, LiveDemo gets result such as "Deluxe Green Bo", "Poke Green", and "Green Symphony", but my result is "Green Qalat", "Asociacion Cannabica GREEN PLANET", "Green Cafe".
Why are they different? And where my result come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the https://serpwow.com/docs/search-api/overview documentation suggests, you need to send the location params or else whatever server is superwow using, it will take that as its local. so try sending your location in your API and check the result on the LiveDemo. I am sure it will match. You can simply specify a single location that you think you app will be mostly used in but if you get a different location, you can replace it with a new one.